# I'm Very Memorable, But I'll Make You Forgettable

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Do you think that I can hide you from your friends?
> I'll have them seeing you through a different lens.
>
> So don't be surprised if you can't recognize,
> Given that I'm a very familiar guise.
>
> Underneath all these lies, I'll protect what you hide,
> I'll convince all their eyes, your secret is what I pride.
>
> So beware what you see, this face smiling happily.
> Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily.

What am I?

Comment: Could this be describing rot13(ebg13)? ;)

Comment: @maxathousand, very interesting theory. Maybe I'll make a future puzzle about that.

Comment: Love this riddle, especially the title. Also, looking forward to your potential future puzzle! DVL2 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Third try!

> Makeup

Do you think that I can hide you from your friends?
I'll have them seeing you through a different lens.

> People look totally different with makeup on.

So don't be surprised if you can't recognize,
Given that I'm a very familiar guise.

> Celebrities with no make are almost unrecognizable

Underneath all these lies, I'll protect what you hide,

> Maybe dark circles under your eyes.

I'll convince all their eyes, your secret is what I pride.

> People put a lot on.

So beware what you see, this face smiling happily.
Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily.

> They think they have to in this society. (and makeup can run if you cry).

Hidden hint

> The first letter of each line spells disguise.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Comment: "So beware what you see, this face smiling happily." : rot13(Qba'g jngpu zbivrf gung zvtug znxr lbh pel.) "Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily." : rot13(Vs lbh pel, lbh zrff hc lbhe znxrhc.)

Comment: @Joe-You-Know If this is the correct answer, click the green tick next to this answer, it should be under the upvotes and downvotes

Comment: @SydneySleeper, I always wait 24 hours before acccepting. But thanks for the reminder :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer might be

> Sunglasses

As Shahriar pointed out

> The acrostic spells DISGUISE

Do you think that I can hide you from your friends?

> Sunglasses can be used as part of a disguise.

I'll have them seeing you through a different lens.

> Glasses have lenses

So don't be surprised if you can't recognize,

> It's not always easy to recognise a person if they are wearing sunglasses.

Given that I'm a very familiar guise.

> Sunglasses are worn by people in many different situations, especially on a sunny day.

Underneath all these lies, I'll protect what you hide,

> Your eyes, *the windows to the soul*.

I'll convince all their eyes, your secret is what I pride.

> Your eyes can often give away what you are thinking.

So beware what you see, this face smiling happily. 
Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily.

> Even though somebody appears to be smiling, you cannot always tell their state of mind unless you see there eyes.

Comment: Another really good guess. This one is the closest yet, though not quite what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Photographs?

Do you think that I can hide you from your friends?
I'll have them seeing you through a different lens.

> Photographs are captured through different camera lens

So don't be surprised if you can't recognize,
Given that I'm a very familiar guise.

> quite old photographs of people are almost unrecognizable

Underneath all these lies, I'll protect what you hide,
I'll convince all their eyes, your secret is what I pride.

> There's a saying "People change, photos doesn't"

So beware what you see, this face smiling happily.
Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily.

> Say cheese doesn't always mean that you are happy to be clicked

Comment: Whoa great answer!

Comment: Agreed, this is a great answer. And it fits this really well. Although it's not what I was looking for, this may fit all the clues perfectly. +1

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I am now thinking of rot13(Qvffbpvngvir Vqragvgl Qvfbeqre). What do you think?

Comment: Ooh, that's another good answer. However, QuantumTwinkie got the right answer.

Comment: Oh. That's great!

Answer (score 4):

Is it-

> Disguise , that is written in the acrostic.

Comment: It is a type of one, though much more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Costume

Do you think that I can hide you from your friends?

> They may not recognise you.

I'll have them seeing you through a different lens.

> Maybe you are wearing a mask.

So don't be surprised if you can't recognize,
Given that I'm a very familiar guise.

> Make, funny-nose-and-glasses, or a clown

Underneath all these lies, I'll protect what you hide,
I'll convince all their eyes, your secret is what I pride.

> Mask or face paint.

So beware what you see, this face smiling happily.

> Umm, a creepy clown smile/face paint.

Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily.

> Halloween costumes?

Hidden hint

> The first letter of each line spells disguise.

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for, but a great guess nonetheless. It's in the right direction.

Comment: Is it a type of rot13(Pbfghzr)? @Joe-You-Know

Comment: In the strict definition, I would say no. It's something everyone sees every day.

Answer (score 4):

Well, perhaps many answers are provided, but I prefer going with

> A mask

Which hides one's identity and also gives a memorable experience.

Comment: The true answer is a type of this, but really good guess.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Alcohol?

Do you think that I can hide you from your friends?

> People often drink in social situations to "loosen up", which could be thought of as hiding your true personality.

I'll have them seeing you through a different lens.

> You act different when you consume alcohol.

So don't be surprised if you can't recognize,
Given that I'm a very familiar guise.

> People don't realize how it is affecting them in the moment.

Underneath all these lies, I'll protect what you hide,
I'll convince all their eyes, your secret is what I pride.

> The alcohol will shadow your real personality?

So beware what you see, this face smiling happily.

> Not sure about this one.

Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily.

> The alcohol eventually wears off and you go back to normal. Possibly with a hangover, which could make someone unhappy.

Comment: An interesting interpretation. The answer is a little more directly related to the hints than this.

Answer (score 3):

Another Guess

> Contacts

Do you think that I can hide you from your friends?
I'll have them seeing you through a different lens.

> They might not know you need glasses.

So don't be surprised if you can't recognize,
Given that I'm a very familiar guise.

> Lots of people have them!

Underneath all these lies, I'll protect what you hide,
I'll convince all their eyes, your secret is what I pride.

> You can hide your eye color or that you have bad eye sight.

So beware what you see, this face smiling happily.
Ere what you were, will be forced upon you unhappily.

> It hurts to put them in???

Comment: I'm glad the answers are starting to get much closer to what I intended it to, but these answers are focusing too much on the eyes alone. It's something people see everyday, that constantly lies to people, which may be covering up for some sort of unhappiness.

Comment: Could it be rot13(Znxrhc)? @Joe-You-Know

Comment: Yes, yes it very well could be.

Comment: Should I answer with it or edit my post? @Joe-You-Know or is it wrong? :)

Comment: It's different enough where you can post it as a different answer. It's right.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is my first post, and this riddle is nice.

My first guess is

> death. It is a sort of mask, may make your friends see you through a different lens, can be familiar, and protect your secrets...

My second guess, probably better, is

> any social media platform.

Comment: *Hello!* Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**! Congratulations on your very first post! I am glad it contains spoiler tags/quotes (so as to not, well, spoil an idea or potential answer to users who might be attempting to solve the riddle). However, since you are new to the *Stack Exchange* community (let alone this site!), I strongly suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help); and since you have already answered well, I suppose you can skip that part and head [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). *Happy Puzzling!* :D